# Why install Java separately in a browser?

Tags: java, browser

I am trying to understand why we need to install Java within a browser despite having a `JDK`/`JRE` installed on the desktop.

When a browser prompts us to install `Java` , are we actually installing a separate (may be a more condensed version of) `JRE` ? How is this different from `JRE` that is installed on the desktop ?

Does the java installed in a browser interact with the one installed on the desktop ?

Say for instance , my web page is running applets. I need to run the applets (bytecodes) on a `JVM` right ? Why can't the browser just run this on the jre installed on the desktop ?

Can some one help me understand this better ?

Comment: Even if you have a JRE, your browser may not be configured to communicate with that JRE. The browser will need code and configuration to access the features of that JRE. Additionally, other functionality such as the security filtering of applets, the applet libraries, and the control panels used to configure the browser plugin need to be installed and configure. For example, on some Linux distros, this is a separate package called "icedtea".

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser can't access JVM installed on that machine/host. It's mainly due to security reason. If it's allowed, just think what not we will be able to do through applications running in your browser. It will create plethora of security problems. Designers have intentionally put this restriction. 
To execute applets and some other programs you need a separate JRE/Java for your browser.

And similarly, your host can't use Java installed in browser.